# Storing boost sockets in vectors

Tags: c++, sockets, boost, vector, boost-asio

Heres the code. I get the following errors:

```
In member function ‘void socks4Server::listener(int)’:
sock4.cpp:16:49: error: no matching function for call to ‘std::vector<boost::shared_ptr<boost::asio::basic_stream_socket<boost::asio::ip::tcp>>>::push_back(boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket*)’ sockets.push_back(new tcp::socket(io_service));
```

Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/thread/thread.hpp>
using boost::asio::ip::tcp;
using namespace boost;
using namespace std;

class socks4Server{
public:
    boost::asio::io_service io_service;
    bool online;

    void listener(int port){
        tcp::acceptor accept(io_service,tcp::endpoint(tcp::v4(),port));
        vector<shared_ptr<tcp::socket> > sockets;
        while(online){
            sockets.push_back(new tcp::socket(io_service));
            cout<<"new socket thing";
        }
    }

    socks4Server(int port){
        online=true;
        std::thread listen(&socks4Server::listener,this,port);
        listen.detach();
    }
};

int main(){
    socks4Server server(8080);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no implicit conversion from a raw pointer to a shared pointer, so you can't directly push a raw pointer onto a vector of shared pointers. Use one of the following:

```
sockets.push_back(shared_ptr<tcp::socket>(new tcp::socket(io_service)));
sockets.push_back(make_shared<tcp::socket>(io_service));
sockets.emplace_back(new tcp::socket(io_service));  // C++11 or later
```

Also, be careful with dumping both `std` and `boost` into the global namespace. There are many names (such as `shared_ptr`) defined in both namespaces, so such indiscriminate pollution is likely to cause ambiguity.