# How to properly store asio connections and reuse them? (non-boost)

Tags: c++, asio

I am trying to understand basic ASIO (non-boost) but I am having issues understanding how you can store sockets to reuse them later. I was looking at this post: [Storing boost sockets in vectors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25394988/storing-boost-sockets-in-vectors) and tried to reimplement it in my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <asio.hpp>
#include <memory>

std::vector<std::shared_ptr<asio::ip::tcp::socket>> clients;

int main() {
    std::cout << "Starting server..." << "\n";

    try {
        asio::io_context io_context;
        asio::ip::tcp::acceptor acceptor(io_context, asio::ip::tcp::endpoint(asio::ip::tcp::v4(), 6666)); /* Ports below 1025 doesn't work due to permission problem? */

        for (;;) {
            asio::ip::tcp::socket socket(io_context);
            acceptor.accept(socket);
   
            std::string message = std::to_string(clients.size());
            asio::error_code ignored_error;
            asio::write(socket, asio::buffer(message), ignored_error);

            std::shared_ptr<asio::ip::tcp::socket> newconn = std::make_shared<asio::ip::tcp::socket>(std::move(socket)); 
            clients.push_back(newconn);

            /* This does not work */
            for(auto &x : clients) {
                std::string msg = "hello";
                asio::write(x, asio::buffer(msg), ignored_error);
            }

        }
        
    } catch (std::exception &e) {
        std::cerr << e.what() << std::endl;
    }

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

But the code snippet for looping over the clients does not seem to work. Am I implementing this incorrectly or is my understanding of `shared_ptr`'s just too poor?

**Question:** how can I store asio sockets in a vector and reuse them later to send messages?

Comment: You must get familiar with basic C++ concepts: RAII, valueness, copy vs move syntax and semantics, value vs reference vs pointer syntax and semantics. There are a bunch of problems in the above snippet. But before you learn the basics, correcting them won't stop you from shooting yourself in the foot.

Comment: @Red.Wave, I agree, I was not properly understanding Asio which is why I am testing out things which might be bad practise or even completly bad. Would you be kind to point out the "bunch of problems" you find in my code above?

Comment: I was initially disslexed to see a use-after-move in the snippet which would lead to troubles. Accept my Sincere Apologies.

Comment: @Red.Wave, no worries! The fault was completely mine. I am grateful you were so kind to point out my issues. We can only learn by understanding our mistakes :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's strange that this line works: `asio::write(socket, asio::buffer(message), ignored_error);` because you moved a socket before `std::shared_ptr<asio::ip::tcp::socket> newconn = std::make_shared<asio::ip::tcp::socket>(std::move(socket));` and later tried to use it. In a range based for you get `x` which is reference to a `shared_ptr<socket>`. I think you should use `asio::write(*x, asio::buffer(message), ignored_error);` if function `write` uses `socket` and not `shared_ptr<socket>`.

Comment: You are absolutely right about the line that should not work. I copied my code to another file to make it cleaner and must have reordered it somehow. It should now be correct in the question.

Comment: And as you said it should be `*x` in order to use the socket. I will suggest an edit to your answer so we include the code and then I will mark it as accepted. :)

Answer (score 0):

The answer by @Cycxyz https://stackoverflow.com/a/72573845/8204677 assisted me in resolving the issue. But just to clarify for others (since I was not allowed to edit Cycxyz answer due to stackoverflow standards).

The code which had the issue:

```
/* This does not work */
for(auto &x : clients) {
    std::string msg = "hello";
    asio::write(x, asio::buffer(msg), ignored_error);
}
```

Was resolved with this code:

```
/* This DOES work */
for(auto &x : clients) {
    std::string msg = "hello";
    asio::write(*x, asio::buffer(msg), ignored_error);
}
```

The issue was caused due to:

> In a range based for you get x which is reference to a
> shared_ptr. I think you should use asio::write(*x,
> asio::buffer(message), ignored_error); if function write uses socket
> and not shared_ptr.

Explained in the post I linked to.